# How add action on Toolbar (AppCompat v21) at right side

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

How can I add action (icon) on Toolbar (AppConpat v21+)? Like 3-dot icon on right side.

[image]

I can create this action icons via `onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)`:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate( R.menu.menu, menu);
    menu.clear();
    MenuItem menuItemReload = menu.add( getResources().getString( R.string.sReload));
    menuItemReload.setNumericShortcut( '0')
                  .setIcon( ResourcesCompat.getDrawable( getResources(), android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sync, getActivity().getTheme()));
    if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)  menuItemReload.setShowAsAction( MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
}
```

I not found any information inside `getSupportActionBar()` about add actions.

Is there exist different method add icons to Toolbar?

Comment: define menu.xml and add item with showAsAction 'never'.

Answer (score -1):

Did you set the AppCompatToolBar correctly in your AppCompatActivities onCreate()?

```
Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
```

After initializing it this way onCreateOptionsMenue() should work as intended.